# Are there any Android YouTube Player Flags?

Tags: android, youtube

My goal is to launch a video in the YouTube player, and then return to my app. I realize I can't control what's going on in another app, BUT I'm wondering if the YouTube app supports any kind of flags or data set in the calling Intent that might support this functionality.

Anyone aware of any?

I cannot find any documentation on the YouTube app/activities. I had to watch the logs just to figure out which activity to call in the first place (so the choose app dialog didn't appear).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like they have separate [API client library](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/) (.jar) which you can include in your app.